# DataException - Cannot attach file as database EntityFramework in C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I was working on Console Application, before. I was able to access Database. Today, I wanted to take one step further and added Web API project to my solution. My main concern is to use the database I created for the first project. You can see the error I am getting below, later I will explain what I did so far:

> DataException was unhandled by user code
>
> {"An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the
>   InnerException for details."}

So I looked the **InnerException** and

> InnerException: {"Cannot attach the file
>   'C:\Projects\BilyonerParse\BilyonerParse.Web\App_Data\BilyonerParse.Database.FootballContext.mdf'
>   as database 'BilyonerParse.Database.FootballContext'."}

So, step by step, I created new WebAPI project inside my solution then create a new Controller class and write only two methods(you can see it below). Then I tried to connect existing Database from Tools->Connect to Database and with specifying the name of DB. Lastly, because I was getting error about name of the DB, I added to Web.Config what I had got in App.Config in the first project since it specify the EntityFramework rules.

Please find the mentioned files below.

The Controller class:

```
namespace BilyonerParse.Web.Controllers
{
    public class FootballMatchesController : ApiController
    {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public List<FootballMatch> Get()
    {
        IFootballMatchRepository repo = new FootballMatchRepository(new FootballContext());

        return repo.GetAllFootballMatches().ToList();
    }

    public FootballMatch GetFootballMatch(int id)
    {
        IFootballMatchRepository repo = new FootballMatchRepository(new FootballContext());

        return repo.GetFootballMatch(id);
    }
}
```

The Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

The below part is taken from the App.Config in the first project:

```
<configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Below you can find the project folders hiearachy

[image]

That is what I have done in total. I am asking because I could not resolve the problem. Hope you can help me.

Please let me know if you need more information&detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a connection string so EF is falling back to defaults. Try adding a connection string with the name of your context:

```
<add name="FootballContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BilyonerParse.Database.FootballContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well it brought another error which says "sqlException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: What line is crashing and what is the inner exception?

Comment: InnerException this time is null and it crashes at the Get() method's return part. As I assume, crashes when it tries to refer repo. Would you like to see the repo also?

Comment: :An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: Connection string does not match where your existing database is or you don't have needed access rights. Is there a file in your App_Data folder and what is it called?

Comment: In the first project, there is a file named "Database" and inside of it the DB file exists. I will share of a photo of it in the question

Comment: You mean a folder named "Database" ? With the above connection string it is going to look for a file named "BilyonerParse.Database.FootballContext.mdf" in the folder App_Data of the project that contains your context (FootballContext). You can either move the file there or change the connection string to match the location.

Comment: Yes the Database is a directory. What might be the right connection string? As name, should I give its path?

Comment: So the mdf is in that Database folder (only shows context) ? Locate the mdf and replace "|DataDirectory|\BilyonerParse.Database.FootballContext.mdf" with the full path "C:\Projects\BilyonerParse\BilyonerParse\Database\FootballContext.mdf" etc.

Comment: Yeah the mdf is in that database folder. They are in the same solution but in different projects. Just wonder, does the behaviour of the WebAPI projects to look the app_data folder by default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104317/discussion-between-kutay-demireren-and-steve-greene).

Comment: Sorry, in and out today. Try hard coding a path to the file.